# How do you use Russian for all functions

Tags: languages

This is *not* a duplicate, as there are none that answer this question that I can find.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

This returns error whenever I try to do stuff like:

```
\title{россиан калкулус}
\author{зак алкер}
\date{}
\maketitle
```

(Made up Russian)

This just returns an error, but when I replace the russian with English words, it works just fine. I want to write a report in Russian, but I can't figure out how. How would you do this in techworks?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If your document is in Russian, you should switch the languages in the options to babel: Russian should be called last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the main language of the document is Russian, you should declare the language *last* in the options to `babel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\title{россиан калкулус}
\author{зак алкер}
\date{}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Is there any chance you can use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? If so, use it along with an OpenType font that features Cyrillic characters and you should be in business.

An MWE; use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % or any other OpenType font that features Cyrillic characters
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
\title{россиан калкулус}
\author{зак алкер}
\date{}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest this way, too. I use XeLaTeX with Japanese.